# Not getting all data for specific date

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm working on a travel history report which requires that I get all reports from the previous date. For testing, I've been using a JQuery date picker to choose a previous date and a current date.

The issue I'm having is when I query for the ignition on+off reports from that specific date, for some reason there is a time difference of +3 hours so my query doesn't grab all of the data from that day.

Below is the loop I'm using to populate the array and compare the results.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        //$time[$s] = mysql_result($result,$s);
        if($row['Msg'] == 'Ignition Off' && $prev_time!=0){
            //echo "<br>". strftime('%I:%M %p', $row['Date'])."-". strftime('%I:%M %p', $prev_time)."=".($row['Date']-$prev_time)."<br>";
            $d_time+=$row['Date']-$prev_time;
        }

    $prev_time=$row['Date'];
    }

    $d_time=$d_time/3600;
```

First result: `11:41 PM-11:04 PM=2207(difference in epoch)`
The times on our website would be `8:04` for ignition on and `8:41` for ignition off for the same report.

But since there is a 3 hour difference, my loops stop after 11:59pm since that would be the next day and forgets about the other data because it's no longer the previous day.

Any suggestions (if understand what I just said) would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the query as well:

```
$queryt = "SELECT  `D_ID` ,  `Msg` ,  `Date` FROM  `211590` WHERE  (`Msg` =  'Ignition On' OR  `Msg` =  'Ignition Off') AND ( `Date` BETWEEN $prev_day AND $cur_day) ORDER BY `D_ID` ASC  LIMIT 100 ";
```

Comment: Are you sure that the server + client timezone is set the same? Eg, if your computers timezone is GMT+1 your server also needs to be GMT+1

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm in Connecticut and the data I've been testing was reported from NY, so I don't understand where this difference in time is coming from.

Comment: It seems like I would have to adjust the time zone after the previous and current dates get assigned to their respective variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to indicate 2 problems: different local time vs server time AND classic problem with gps tracking application of establishing on/off.

first, remember that you have 3 different timezones at play:

1. timezone registered on your gps tracker (in case of using specific hardware and not cell phone)
2. timezone at server location / server configuration (sql time)
3. local timezone of observer

since you talking about 3 hours, may i guess that you are operating locally in the brasilia / buenos aires timezone (-3 gmt)?  remember, your browser will indicate your local time, while your server may be on GMT proper.

regarding ignition ON and OFF times, remember that you may turn vehicle ON at 11 PM and OFF at 1 AM.  in my system, i use FIRST IGNITION ON and LAST IGNIITION OFF events calculated in terms of the observer's local time OR in international tracker software, in (optional) local time where vehicle is located.

i also save them as events (pulse/heartbeat, alarm, ignition, door open, battery low, etc etc etc) Id_event with an additional table called Events (Id_Event, Ds_Event).

and i have a table which is basically Id_Tracker, Id_Event, Datestamp, Lat (optional), Lng (optional - many events occur underground, in tunnels, in garages where location data is unavailable)

EDIT:
you should also save your datestamp in unixtime (GMT) with no timezone. you then use unixtime (GMT) in your select statement and adjust it with whatever local timezone you want to apply (when does your "day" start?  est?  edt?  cst?  gmt?)

Comment: It seems like I would have to adjust the time zone after the previous and current dates get assigned to their respective variables.

Comment: you need to adjust timezone BEFORE submitting SELECT.  do everything in unixtime gmt and adjust your select accordingly (either automatic verification of system time [javascript+jquery/ajax] or verification of server time [php] or manual input by user [javascript+jquery/ajax] or variable POST).

Comment: I can't up vote yet, don't have enough reputation for it, trust me I tried. Thank you though!

Comment: Or as I should say, muito obrigado!